# Share connections between PHP scripts

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have a PHP script running on a webserver that sends requests to a distant API (REST API over HTTPs, using CURL). Each time a user performs a given action, the PHP script will need to create a new connection to the distant API.

Is there a way to share connection between PHP scripts? This would save time (TCP connection setup, SSL handshake etc...).

Thank you!
PS: I can't let the script run forever as the script is invoked by a webpage request, and multiple scripts may have to run in parallel if multiple requests arrive simultaneously

Comment: Have you considered scheduling a job that kicks off multiple cURL requests? This would make the end user experience fast and responsive without having your web service timeout on you.

Comment: what do you mean? have a job that creates cURL requests that would then be re-used by the PHP script?

Comment: In a word - No, You can't pass on a TCP connection to another web-service via your web-service. You may be able to persistently extend the TCP timeout but it's the distant API that may close the connection first, and then you're back to square one. Unless you have the ability to keep the distant connection open, or stream data via another service, I do not believe this is possible.

Comment: Ok. What about setting up an Nginx reverse proxy that points to the distant API as upstream server along with a keepalive>0? Thanks

Comment: Also scheduling a job would be a nicer way to handle user requests - rather than waiting on the distant API to respond to a request, you can quickly schedule a job, get a cron job to pick it up and notify the user once it's done. If speed is critical, this would make your application feel nice and snappy and the API's response speed won't be an issue.

Comment: Potentially could work, try serverfault.com as that would be a question for the Sys-admin's